New Creality branded direct extruder clicks, won't extrude
I have an Ender 3 Pro (4.2.2 board). I just installed the Creality branded direct extruder/hot end.
I was going to try and calculate my steps/mm for the extruder, but I am just getting clicks from the extruder. I can manually release the extrude and push filament through.
I have the Z height about 50 mm over the bed, I have the hot end at 210 °C, and using Creality PLA.
Since it is a brand new extruder/hot end way above the bed, new hot end, most of the fixes don't apply. The only thing that I see is that the tension may be too high, but I cannot see how to adjust it on this extruder.
Is there a way to do this, or is there something else I should be looking at?

Could you add which extruder-hotend combo you have? Also, what stepper drivers are on board on the 4.2.2 board? It seems that Creality has used this board to place any left over/available drivers ranging from 2208/9 to 4988's. Normally it would have the non-silent 4988's installed. I was thinking that the stepper may not receive enough current.

It is the Ender 3 direct drive extruding kit. Amazon has it listed as model number US4-ENDER3JINDUANJUCHU-FBA or Asian B08J7,N2KNZL. My board has the 4988 drivers. Attached extruder to x position motor, and still just clicked   -alan

0scar was correct, my Vref for the extruder was too low. It was at 0.7 V
I raised it up to 1.1 V, and all seems to be working now.
I will go back and check the other Vrefs later on.

You're welcome, please do not forget to accept your question after 48 hours! When a question has an accepted answer it will not pop up once in a while in the queue!
